# BackboneJS nested view not rendering

Tags: backbone.js

I have backbonejs `form` inside the lightbox with `html` `<select>` as child view.
For the `select` `<option>` data I am loading from server and I have separate model and collection for this `select`

```
<select name="organization" id="organization" class="main__form--select main__form--select--js">
    <option value="no">Organizations not found, Please add one</option>
</select>
```

Model for option (optionModel)

```
return Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        "name" : 'KFC',
        "email" : 'info@kfc.com',
        "image" : '/kfc.jpg',
        "descrption" : 'Lorem Ipsum'
    }
});
```

This is view for the model

```
return Backbone.View.extend({    
    model : optionModel,
    template : _.template(template),
    render : function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));     
        return this;
    }
});
```

This is options collection

```
return Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : optionModel,
    getQuery : function(){
        //all my query codes
    }
});
```

Options collections view `render()` code

```
this.collection.each(function (optionModel) {
    // inserting each options view to an array
    _this._optionsViewArray.push(
        new OptionView({
            model: optionModel
        }).render().el
    );
});
//inserting array to collection view container
_this.$el.html(_this._optionsViewArray);
return this;
```

My Parent view (form view) i create after render function with underscore `_.wrap` and inside that function

```
//<select>
var _selector = this.$el.find('#organization');

optionsView = new OptionsCollectionView({
    collection : optionsCollection,
    $el: _selector
});
optionsCollection.getQuery();
optionsView.render();
```

But Form is loading perfectly and Options collection querying successfully but nothing changes on `<select>` html, It's not updating.

Comment: What is `_this`..? What is `_optionsViewArray`..? If its a javascript array, who told you jQuery `html` method accepts an array..? Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `getQuery()` does an asynchronous query (either using jQuery or `Collection.fetch()`), the problem (or at least one problem) is that you're calling `optionsView.render()` to soon, before the query results have returned.

You could throw in an arbitrary 5 second timeout to verify that this is the problem like this: `setTimeout(function() { optionsView.render(); }, 5 * 1000);`, but the correct way to do it is to call render from a jQuery `done` handler function (`$.ajax({done: function() { ... }})`) or (better) a Backbone `sync` event handler (this will only get called if you did the query via a Backbone collection `fetch()`): `optionsCollection.on('sync', function() { ... });`

Answer (score 0):

You example is incomplete. However, given that fetches are generally asynchronous in Backbone and jQuery, this is the most obvious issue is that `optionsView.render` will run before `optionsCollection` has had a chance to fully load the collection. You can remedy this by listening to the collection update event:

```
optionsView = new OptionsCollectionView({
    collection : optionsCollection,
   $el: _selector
});
optionsView.listenTo(optionsCollection, 'update', optionsView.render);
optionsCollection.getQuery();
```

You could listen to the `sync` event instead, but listening to `update` means that local changes to the collection will also trigger updating your view.

There is also an issue with your render function, as you are passing an array of html elements into the jQuery html function.

```
render: function() {

    var $el = this.$el;

    $el.empty();

    this.collection.each(function (optionModel) {

        var view = new OptionView({ model: optionModel });

        $el.append(view.render().$el);

    });

    return this;

}
```

However you may be better off using a standard collection view pattern, or something like Backbone.CollectionView - http://rotundasoftware.github.io/backbone.collectionView/